# What are some common AWS Lamdba (specific) Security Pitfalls, Auditing Tools, and Methods of Mitigation?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, cloud-computing, aws

I am writing a research paper detailing the security vulnerabilities of serverless AWS lambda applications, and how to prevent them. I am also compiling a list of security auditing tools that are designed to target serverless lambda applications.

I am trying to compile an exhaustive list of known lambda specific vulnerabilities, common mistakes (such as AWS lax permission policies), and how to prevent or mitigate against them. So far I have:

- Remote command injection is possible, particularly if data is not sanitized correctly.
- Leaked AWS credentials also obviously affect lambda as well, this is a very common mistake (such as credentials stashed in git commits, as demonstrated on [flaws.cloud](http://flaws.clould))
- API Gateway is always publicly accessible, so we need to take the necessary precautions to secure access to our internal APIs, preferably with IAM roles.
- Lambda costs incurred during a DoS attack ("cost attacks")
- Functions often are given more permissions than necessary which can lead to compromise
- Unused functions accidentally, or lazily left around can turn into attack surfaces.
- From [rhino security labs aws writeup:](https://rhinosecuritylabs.com/aws/aws-privilege-escalation-methods-mitigation/)

  - It is possible to pass a new role to a lambda function and then invoke it.
  - It is possible to pass a role to a new Lambda function and trigger it with DynamoDB
  - It is possible to modify the code of an existing lambda function and exploit it

For tools used to audit AWS, so far I have found quite a few:

- [Aws-Pentest-Tools by Rhino Security Labs](https://github.com/RhinoSecurityLabs/Security-Research/tree/master/tools/aws-pentest-tools)
- [AWS 'Arsenal of Tools' by toniblyx](https://github.com/toniblyx/my-arsenal-of-aws-security-tools)

I am trying to make the list if known Lambda-specific vulnerabilities & common mistakes as exhaustive as possible. Personally I am not terribly experienced with AWS or Lambda, so I wanted to ask those of you in the security community that have real world experience deploying, maintaining, and/or auditing Lambda applications:

- What are the most common mistakes that administrators make when deploying lambda applications, and how can they be prevented?
- What are some common vulnerabilities specifically having to do with lambda instances running Python code, and how can they be avoided? (Interested to hear about other languages as well)
- Has anyone with experience administering lambda encountered a scenario involving any of the vulnerabilities on my list? I would love to hear your story.
- What else should I add to these lists?

Essentially I am asking for help making these lists as exhaustive as possible; particular the list of vulnerabilities. *Real world experience and examples would be much appreciated.* The main question is: What am I missing?